# How to select shortest GPS coordinate according to given condition?

Tags: php, mysql, gps, coordinates

I have table `GPS_tbl` in mysql database `my_db`. In `GPS_tbl` there are five columns `1)uid 2)latitude 3)longitude 4)regid 5)status`. In column `5)status` there are two types of values are stored as varchar one is `free` and other is `move`. What i am doing right now is when user send his/her gps coordinates in terms of `latitude` and `longitude` through `POST()`, so to select the shortest coordinate from columns `2)latitude 3)longitude`  i am using **Pythagorean theorem** so by using this i compare these user sent coordinate with already stored coordinates in columns `2)latitude 3)longitude` and select the `4)regid` against it. Now what i want is only select that `4)regid` against shortest coordinate from `2)latitude 3)longitude` whose `5)status` value is `free`.

At the moment i am using this query, which is only selecting `4)regid` against `shortest coordinate` and not taking care of `status` value:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT regid, sqrt(latitude-$lati)+sqrt(longitude-$longi) AS SQRT_DIST FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1");
```

GPS_tbl

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|     uid      | latitude   | longitude   |   regid     |   status    |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      1       |  73.3433   |  18.5223    |APA91W-ClDoS |   move      |
|              |            |             |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      2       |  43.3433   |  24.5523    |BON91W-ClDoS |   free      |
|              |            |             |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      3       |  55.3433   |  37.5323    |WCD71P-ClDoS |   free      |
|              |            |             |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      4       |  65.3433   |  47.5323    |ZCF71D-ClDoS |   move      |
|              |            |             |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      5       |  85.3433   |  27.5323    |XVD73A-ClDoS |   free      |
|              |            |             |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do you mean "nearest"?

Comment: @Strawberry no i already implemented that as u can see i explained this above, now what i want is first only sort coordinates against whose status value is "free" then apply this query $result = mysql_query("SELECT regid, sqrt(latitude-$lati)+sqrt(longitude-$longi) AS SQRT_DIST FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1");

Comment: Sooo `WHERE status = 'free'`?

Comment: @Sammitch i tried to do this it gives me error.

Comment: In other words: "yes, I mean 'nearest' (or 'shortest distance'), not 'shortest'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pythagorean distance between two points is calculated by:

```
distance = sqrt( (x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 )
```

That's  not what your query is calculating:

```
SELECT regid, sqrt(latitude-$lati)+sqrt(longitude-$longi) AS SQRT_DIST FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1
```

You've got the square root of two values added together, not the square root of the sum. Try this instead:

```
SELECT regid, sqrt( (latitude-$lati)*(latitude-$lati) +(longitude-$longi)*(longitude-$longi) ) AS SQRT_DIST FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1
```

Now, a couple of things.

1. This distance calculation is an adequate approximation if the distance between the two points is small, but once you get into larger values, it will get farther and farther from the true value. Why? Because the surface of the earth is the surface of a sphere, not a plane. To calculate the correct value, google "Great Circle Distance"
2. Somebody else will probably mention this, but here goes 1) don't use `mysql_` functions: they're deprecated; and 2) your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: `POW(latitude-$lati, 2)` is more concise.

Comment: @Kryten ohh thanks a lot you saved my life as i am weak in maths. okay so please help me what i want is first sort only those "status" whose value is "free" then apply this algorithm SELECT regid, sqrt( (latitude-$lati)*(latitude-$lati) +(longitude-$longi)*(longitude-$longi) ) AS SQRT_DIST FROM GPS_tbl ORDER BY SQRT_DIST limit 1.

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause: `WHERE status='free'` after the table name.